# I can't run javascript on notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++

So I found online javascript tutorials and I downloaded notepad++ to write my code. The problem is that I can't run it. I tried saving it as .html and then running it with mozilla but then I got the whole code written into the mozilla window. 
I mean if the code is 
`var x = 5;
console.log(x);`
I get this whole thing written there, not executed.

Comment: In order for it to run in a browser it needs to be enclosed in `<script>` tags and you have to have the console open to see the output.

Comment: You can use services like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [jsbin](http://jsbin.com), or [CodePen](http://codepen.io) as simple environments to run JavaScript code. You can also use Node.js to run JavaScript locally.

Comment: Given that there's not much here to go on you should try to provide more information. There's a number of reasons why this might happen It might be as simple as a missing reference to the js.file.

Comment: JavaScript is a client-side script which runs on client browser. If you put whole code together, just think once: how browser will be able to differentiate whether it's a JavaScript or some content to be displayed on the screen. That why we have <script></script> tag.

Comment: Are you sure it's saved as *.html and not *.html.txt?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript needs to be in a `<script>` tag for a HTML file:

```
<script> 
    var x = 5;
    console.log(x);
</script>
```

You can also define the JavaScript in a `.js` file and reference it by doing:

```
<script src="myJSFile.js"></script>
```

In that case you don't need to place `<script>` tags inside the `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not showing file extension in windows, and you think that you are saving it in "index.html" but you are saving as "index.html.txt" and mozilla opens it as a text file